# Double sound android

Tags: android, audio, onclick, android-mediaplayer

```
package project.kalmas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class one extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);
    }

    public void onclick2(View view)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent("project.two");
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void onclick3(View view)
    {
        MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }

    }
```

}
When i click button it play sound then again i click button to stop it wont stop and play sound again which results in double sound playing at one time.Please help

Comment: everytime you click the button you'r creating that sound again. so do this before on click for ex in your oncreate method MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `MediaPlayer` with every click, instead of keeping a reference to the first one. The `MediaPlayer` that is playing the sound is different than the `MediaPlayer` that you are calling `isPlaying()` on. You need to turn the `mp` variable into a field so you can keep a reference to it.

I imagine something like this would work:

```
public class one extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);
    }

    public void onclick2(View view)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent("project.two");
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void onclick3(View view)
    {

        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks vince this works now,but it work's only once start then stop but never start again onclick3,I want it to start-stop-start-stop.....Thanks.

Comment: Per [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), "Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again."

Comment: Disregard my comment about using a boolean field, that was incorrect.